# Cypress --headless still opening browser window on mac os

Tags: cypress

`npx npm run cypress --headless` running this code in my project is still opening up a google chrome user, requiring UI to keep it going

no matter what I try, even uninstalling and reinstalling cypress doesn't fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is:

```
 cypress run
```

Actually by default this command is executed in headless mode, that's why it's not necessary to write --headless. And if you want to run it in headed mode, then:

```
 cypress run --headed
```

Comment: Im well aware that’s the default way, but it doesn’t work, that’s why I’m asking a question here

Comment: Do you mean that you tried "cypress run" instead of the command in your question, and it did not work either?

Comment: Yes, that’s what I mean